# Parse | Push Notification Straight Into Web View, How?

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, push-notification, tableview

I've searched in the web, parse docs and ask many people but no one can point me how to do it.
I have an RSS app who getting the articles into a UITableView.
when I'm sending a Push it's open the app itself but not the article I want to (well obviously since I don't know how to code that) .
Can anyone please give me ideas how to do it ? 
(code sample will be useful as well) .

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to implement your own Receiver class instead of default Parse push receiver and put it into AndroidManifest.xml as follows :

```
<receiver android:name="net.blabla.notification.PushNotifHandler" android:exported="false">
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="net.bla.PUSH_MESSAGE" />
          </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

In your PushNotifHandler.java class you should put some parameters to Intent you will throw as follows :

```
public class PushNotifHandler extends BroadcastReceiver{
    private static final String TAG = PushNotifHandler.class.getSimpleName();
    private static int nextNotifID = (int)(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000);
    private static final long VIBRATION_DURATION = 500;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, ToBeOpenedActivity.class);
            JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));
            fillNotificationData(jsonData, action, resultIntent);

            String title = jsonData.getString("messageTitle") + "";
            String message = jsonData.getString("messageText") + "";

            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.from(context);
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(ToBeOpenedActivity.class);
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                    stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                            0,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                    );

            Notification notification;
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).
                    setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon).
                    setContentTitle(title).
                    setContentText(message).
                    setAutoCancel(true);

            builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
            notification = builder.getNotification();

            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mNotificationManager.notify(TAG, nextNotifID++, notification);

            vibratePhone(context);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void vibratePhone(Context context) {
        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE); 
        vibrator.vibrate(VIBRATION_DURATION);
    }

    private void fillNotificationData(JSONObject json, String action, Intent resultIntent)
            throws JSONException {
        Log.d(TAG, "ACTION : " + action);
        resultIntent.putExtra("paramString", json.getString("paramFromServer"));
    }

}
```

With key "com.parse.Data" you will get parameters sent from your server code as json format.After getting paramString and paramBoolean parameters from this json, you will put these parameters into new Intent you hav created as seen in fillNotificationData method.

Other parts of onReceive method creates a local notification and vibrates the device.

Finally on your activity class onResume() method you will check intent parameters to realize if you are opening the app from push notification or not.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    checkPushNotificationCase(getIntent());
}

private void checkPushNotificationCase(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extraParameters = intent.getExtras();
    Log.d("checking push notifications intent extras : " + extraParameters);
    if (extraParameters != null) {
        if(extraParameters.containsKey("paramString")) {
            // doSomething
        }
    }
}
```

I hope you have asked this question for Android :))

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this for IOS